# How to disable directory listing in the ColdFusion 8 built-in webserver?

Tags: coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 8, and the built-in webserver as a development environment.

In order to access sites hosted by the CF built-in webserver you put site directories in `cf_root/wwwroot/` and can find them at `localhost:8500/`, and by default the contents of the directory `cf_root/wwwroot` are listed at `localhost:8500` and any directory that does not have an index file will have it's contents listed by default.

I would like to change this.

I do not want directory contents to be displayed to the user because I want to be able to use [localtunnel](https://github.com/progrium/localtunnel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just put an index.cfm file in the wwwroot folder, with nothing in it. That will prevent the directory listing from displaying. So long as their is an index.cfm file, it will be rendered by default.

To disable file browsing completely on the built-in CF server, follow [these instructions](http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/adv_development/config_builtin_webserver/config_builtin_webserver06.html).

Comment: that works for the root, but not for subdirectories, I'd like to do something that works for subdirectories too if possible.

Comment: In that case, give this a try: http://www.adobe.com/support/coldfusion/adv_development/config_builtin_webserver/config_builtin_webserver06.html